# google.script.run and form with input type=file produce string "FileUpload" not a blob

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, file-io, google-drive-api, blob

I use HTMLServices with `google.script.run` calls with form in args and i try to get the image from my form input file field and store it in my drive.

I get the value of all the fields correctly except the photodata field.
`photodata` contain the string "FileUpload" instead of a blob.

I have tested with `.getBlob` for the same result.

Server Side :

```
function setUsager(form) {
  var blob = form.photodata;
  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStingify(blob);
  DriveApp.getFolderById('0B2DdOMvW2Q84N0s4a21LM05wbms').createFile(form.usagerId,blob);
  obj = new {};
  obj.photo = file.getUrl();
  return obj;
}
```

on click Handler

```
  function onUsagerEditFormSubmit() {
    loading(true);
    var form = this.parentNode;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showUsager)
        .withFailureHandler(showError)
        .setUsager(form);      
   
  }
```

And the form :

```html
<form name="usager-edit" id="usager-edit" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="hidden">
    <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="USAGER" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" name="usagerId" id="usagerId" readonly="readonly" />
  </div>
  <div class="field-container">      
    <label for="nom">Nom</label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom">
  </div>
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
    <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom">
  </div>
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="photo">Photo</label>
    <input class="file" type="file" name="photodata" id="photodata" accept='image/*'>
    <div id="prev-photo" name="prev-photo"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="myButton" onClick="onUsagerEditFormSubmit" type="button" name="save" id="save-button" value="Sauvegarder" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong createFile method overload.

[image: setUsager]

You are using [createFile(name, content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=es#createFile%28String,String%29), when you should use [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=es#createFile%28BlobSource%29).

```
...
var file = DriveApp.getFolderById('****************************').createFile(blob);
...
```

You must define `file` in order to make: `obj.photo = file.getUrl();`.

Also you can change the following:

```
...
<input class="myButton" onClick="onUsagerEditFormSubmit" type="button" name="save" id="save-button" value="Sauvegarder" />
...
```

by:

```
...
<input class="myButton" onClick="onUsagerEditFormSubmit(this.parentNode)" type="button" name="save" id="save-button" value="Sauvegarder" />
...
```

and

```
  function onUsagerEditFormSubmit() {
    loading(true);
    var form = this.parentNode;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showUsager)
        .withFailureHandler(showError)
        .setUsager(form);    
  }
```

by:

```
  function onUsagerEditFormSubmit(form) {
    loading(true);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showUsager)
        .withFailureHandler(showError)
        .setUsager(form);    
  }
```

Slight changes:

```
...
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStingify(blob);
...
obj = new {};
...
```

by:

```
...
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(blob));
...
var obj = {};
...
```